# Are there any example applications or quick start tutorials for Rapidclipse X?

Tags: rapidclipse

I'm evaluating Rapidclipse X and it would be great if there were demo applications.  A app like the Petstore demo would be terrific.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet. But it is simple. If you can put a specific issue. I can help.
One question: Have you used Rapidclipse before? I mean other than X?